# Pattern in Illustrator has vertical lines when expanding

Tags: path, patterns, pathfinder

I made a hexagonal pattern, when I expand it and use the Crop Pathfinding tool, it created vertical lines inside my pattern, breaking it up into smaller pieces (which is not what I want).

Is there a way to expand my pattern so I can color the individual pieces, while keeping my original pattern shape?

[image]

#### Steps

- Create a square and apply the pattern
- Object -> Expand
- Pathfinder -> Crop

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Shape Builder tool to merge the pieces into hexagons.

Example:

[image]